# get encrypted minio url

Tags: python, minio

I have minio server and i want to download files from it with URL.
so i used the presigned_get_object function but it returned something like this:

```
https://dk-mini-io.darkube.app/media1/user_12/x.txt?X-...
```

but i don't want to show user id (user_12) and bucket name(media1) in URL.
in other words, i want to minio encrypt this information in return URL.
is there any way to do this?

i want to minio encrypt the return URL in the presigned_get_object function.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues with the presigned links.
It seemed to me the best way to go through my own api.
I didnt also find a way to revoke authorization for the generated link, as it seems, the only thing that can be set is the expiration date.
Proxing through my api means at the other end, doupling traffic and resources, as the api access minio first and than gives it back to the user.
For very large files, and high number of requests this is not the best solution.